# Entity Framework Migrations: get name of tables and columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In `DbContext.OnModelCreating` you get a `DbModelBuilder` object. You tell this object the names of tables / columns of your `DbSets` and the relations between the tables.

For example, if you have a class `Country`, and you want to name the table `Countries` (instead of the default `Countrys` you would write:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().ToTable("Countries");
```

Later, when migrating the database to a newer version, method `DbMigration.Up()` is called.

Suppose I want to add a Column with an abbreviated name of the Country (like "UK" for "United Kingdom")

```
public override void Up()
{
     this.AddColumn(..., // name of table
        "Abbreviation",
        column => column.String(nullable: true, maxLength: 10));
}
```

I know that somewhere in my DbContext the actual name of the table that is connected to my `DbSet<Country>` is stored. After all, whenever I save changes that I made to the `DbSet<Country>`, the DbContext knows the name of the table to change.

So to get the name of the table, I thought I had to ask my `DbMigration` which `DbContext` it is migrating, but I can't find this. Even if I had the DbContext, I can't ask it for for its model. I thought this would be in property `DbContext.Configuration`, but the returned `DbContextConfiguration` has no fields to access the names of the tables and columns, like the `ModelBuilder` has.

So: how do I know the actual names of my tables and columns in the version that I am updating in this `DbMigration`?

### Addition after comments

Steve Green proposed to let Entity Framework DbMigration detect that the model has changed. For those interested, this method is known as [Automated Migration](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx).

However, if you want full control of your tables/columns and the relations between the tables, you'll need to do [code-based migrations](https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2012/10/introduction-to-code-first-migrations) (migrations using DbMigrations.Up() and DbMigrations.Down().

If during the creation of your code-first database you don't want the default naming conventions for tables and columns, if you don't want default string lengths, default precision for decimals, etc, you'll have to use fluent API (or attributes).

Similarly, if you don't want the entity framework defaults during migrations, you'll have to write code in `DbMigrations.Up()` and `Down()`.

To keep my example simple, I used class `Country` which by default would have lead to table `Countrys`. But one could think of more complex items, like the maximum field length of a string property, the precision of decimals, of `CascadeOnDelete`

Comment: Why would you manually create a new column instead of letting the diff checker do it? IE add your abberviation to the Country POCO and let EF do its thing.